# How to rename the Azure WebApp URL

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-web-app-service

For numerous time it has happened that our DevOps guys have created a Azure WebApp with incorrect URL.

Which forced us the delete the resource group (as group contains web app, sql azure etc.) And re-create.

Is there a way to re-name /update the Web App URL via powershell Azure API or some hidden azure portal feature?

Comment: Why are you deleting the whole resource group? You can just delete the webapp and recreate it in the same resource group with a different name.

Comment: That's what we have been doing. I'm looking for an option to rename webapp URL.

Comment: What are down votes for? This is a legitimate question.

Comment: Can't rename Free WebApps. It is possible to add Host entry using Powershell to higher tier WebApps ...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's not possible to rename web apps.

And you don't need to delete the whole resource group.  Just delete the one web app and recreate it with the correct name.

Comment: Thanks but, I'm looking for an option to rename the WebApps

Comment: @Myagdi, there is no way to rename your web apps

Answer (score 13):

You can clone the web app , and in the process give the new url.
Remove the earlier web app and you are good to go

Note: "**Clone app is a feature that is only available to apps hosted on Premium App Service Plans**. You can upgrade your App Service Plan to get access to this feature."

Comment: Take into consideration: "Clone app is a feature that is only available to apps hosted on Premium App Service Plans. You can upgrade your App Service Plan to get access to this feature."

Comment: @Germstorm But you can upgrade, make the clone and then downgrade immediately.  No cost.

Comment: Just cloned a web app hosted in an S1 plan.

Answer (score 8):

You can just add the hostname to the resource hosting the web application.

For example from portal.azure.com go to "App Services", choose your service and from the blade search for "domain", then click "Custom domains", then add "hostname" that will ask your DNS, validate and give you the DNS records you need to add, see screenshot below:

[image: Custom domains in Azure]

NOTE: this does not actually rename the resource, the old one will still be a valid alias for the the resource along with the domain name registered in this note.

Answer (score 1):

No :(

Best option is to redeploy. Maybe add a confirmation message of your name? "Are you sure you want to call this resource 'Foobar'"?

Comment: Is this stil true?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to rename your webapp url since it create unique dns and maps. If you still want to do that then use automation script to delete existing and redeploy your code to newly create one.
Ex.
Clone existing => update new url => create new webapp=> delete existing one

Answer (score 1):

I came here for the same reason for my dev site and just gave up and cloned it since it was dev\qc anyway. Took about 5-7 minutes to clone and BOOM, no changes needed and actually was able to update the region to a better one\closer to have a better compare to my prod.

Under Azure App Home page for your app., scroll down on left to "Developer tools" - Select Clone app.   Add a new URL and update area etc.

You can then go and add your custom domain after, etc.

Simple as that..